# Why it reads the file correctly only at second time

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a file which first 64 bytes are:

```
0x00:  01 00 00 10 00 00 00 20 00 00 FF 03 00 00 00 10  
0x10:  00 00 00 10 00 00 FF 03 00 00 00 10 00 00 FF 03  
0x20:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  
0x30:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

When i'm reading the file (mode read and write) at position 26 for 4 bytes I get 0 and the next time (at position 30) i get correctly 4096.

The code is:

```
// read LastDirectoryBlockStartByte...
seekg(26);
char * pCUIBuffer = new char[4];
read(pCUIBuffer, 4);
const unsigned int x1 = gcount ();
const unsigned int LastDirectoryBlockStartByte = *(unsigned int *)pCUIBuffer;

// read LastDirectoryBlockNumberItems...
seekg(30);
read(pCUIBuffer, 4);
const unsigned int x2 = gcount ();
const unsigned int LastDirectoryBlockNumberItems = *(unsigned int *)pCUIBuffer;
```

With gcount() I checked the bytes are read - and this were correctly both times 4.
I have no idea to debug it.

---------- EDIT ----------

When I use the following code (with some dummy before) it reads correctly:

```
char * pCUIBuffer = new char[4];
seekg(26);
read(pCUIBuffer, 4);
const unsigned int x1 = gcount ();
seekg(26);
read(pCUIBuffer, 4);
const unsigned int x2 = gcount ();
const unsigned int LastDirectoryBlockStartByte = *(unsigned int *)pCUIBuffer;

// read LastDirectoryBlockNumberItems...
seekg(30);
read(pCUIBuffer, 4);
const unsigned int x3 = gcount ();
const unsigned int LastDirectoryBlockNumberItems = *(unsigned int *)pCUIBuffer;
```

The difficulty is that the code stands at the begining in a methode. And the "false readed value" has obviously nothing to do with the listed code. Maybe theres a trick with flush or sync (but both I tryed...) or somewhat else...

Comment: Are you on a big-endian or little-endian architecture?

Comment: Show your open statement.  Are you opening with binary mode?

Comment: @gregg: I'm in binary mode...

Comment: @JSBangs: I have to swich high and low and first and second bytes - so 00 10 00 00 is excatly 00 00 10 00 = 4069.

Comment: @oRUMOo, there is no byte swapping visible in your code above. Please post *exactly* what you have, because I can't see any problem in the code that you've posted.

Comment: Why don't you declare CUIBuffer to just be an unsigned long, pass a pointer when reading, and get rid of a lot of noise in the code?

Comment: @unwind: maybe you are right, but it didn't solve the problem. I made it becouse read operates with bytes...

Comment: Please post the code for `gcount()`

Comment: @ Steve Townsend: gcount is an istream methode just istream::gcount()

Comment: So your class inherits from `istream`?

Comment: @Steve Townsend : yes my class CFile inherits from istream. Sorry that I didn't mention it.

Comment: I think you should post the complete method code that fails.  Provided there are no other threads operating on this file, that should be definitive.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: there are sure no other threads operating on this file; and I said the code I present is at the beginning of the method, so the curious behaviour maybe has something to do with file buffers or whatever!

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why reading the same bytes twice should work when reading them once does not.  So more code is required for responders to resolve this.  This code should work, so the problem must be somewhere else, in code we cannot yet see.

Comment: If you make a call to `tellg()`, does it return the stream pointer position you assume you're suppose to be at?  Maybe you can add some `assert()` values to be absolutely sure the stream pointer is in the correct position before making the `read()` call.

Comment: Try enabling exceptions by calling `exceptions (eofbit | failbit | badbit) ;` (or just checking these bits after each call).

Comment: @TonyK: file.exceptions(...) was the perfect hint! thank you!

Comment: @TonyK: can you write a nice answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I'm writing an answer, because my attempt to contact TonyK failes (I asked for writing an answer).

The perfect answer to my question was to enable exceptions by calling `exceptions (eofbit | failbit | badbit)`.

Rumo

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that pCUIBuffer contains a pointer:

```
*(unsigned int *)pCUIBuffer;
```

And then you go get whatever it's pointing at...in RAM.  That could be anything.

Comment: @ Steve Wellens: between new statement and "...*(unsigned int *)pCUIBuffer;" I read the filecontent to pCUIBuffer.

Comment: What? `pCUIBuffer` is a `char*`, and what the OP has is the correct way to get an integral value from a `char*` buffer.

Comment: @Steve: The OP's statement is correct. `pCIUBuffer` *is* a pointer, and this is the correct way to access what it points to, interpreted as an unsigned int.

Comment: @TonyK-  Say he reads the number 1234 from the file and then says it's a pointer.  So he goes to memory address 1234 and gets whatever memory happens to be there and casts it to an unsigned it.  That's what it looks like to me.  Who knows what could be at memory location 1234.

Comment: @Steve: Still wrong. If you don't believe me, just go to http://ideone.com/muDNL and look at the output.

Comment: @TonyK - You are correct, it's been a while since I've worked with C/C++ and had forgotten referring to an array actually refers to the address of the first element (and THAT is what is being deferenced).  I wonder if working with C# has broken me for C++...thanks for taking the time.  PS: Could you downvote my initial response, I wasn't allowed to.